# Python: request to Google Maps API - handshake issue

Tags: python, google-maps

I am making geocoding requests to googles api using requests:

```
geo_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + geo_address + '&key=' + GOOGLE_API_KEY
geo_response = requests.get(url=geo_url, verify=False)
geo = geo_response.json()
```

In my cloud9 IDE it works semalessly.

On my Ubuntu Server with Apache and mod_wsgi it works SOMETIMES, but often it fails with an error in Apaches error.log:

```
   File "/var/virtualenv/primo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 129, in emit
     self.send_mail(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message=html_message)
   File "/var/virtualenv/primo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 132, in send_mail
     mail.mail_admins(subject, message, *args, connection=self.connection(), **kwargs)
   File "/var/virtualenv/primo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 98, in mail_admins
     mail.send(fail_silently=fail_silently)
   File "/var/virtualenv/primo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 303, in send
     return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
   File "/var/virtualenv/primo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
     new_conn_created = self.open()
   File "/var/virtualenv/primo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 64, in open
     self.connection.starttls(keyfile=self.ssl_keyfile, certfile=self.ssl_certfile)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 649, in starttls
     self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, keyfile, certfile)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 487, in wrap_socket
     ciphers=ciphers)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 243, in __init__
     self.do_handshake()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in do_handshake
     self._sslobj.do_handshake()
   error: [Errno 0] Error
```

I do not understand what is going wrong. Can somebody point me in the correct direction, please?

Comment: What version of requests are you using?

Comment: The latest is  2.9.1 now, try upgrading and see if the issue persists

Comment: hehe, just did it a few seconds ago because I realized I was using an older version. now 2.9.1 and the same issue. Sometimes it fails.

Comment: what happens if you re-try the get request?

Comment: It is strange that it sometimes works but the error message is not exactly informative, what version of openssl  do you have on the server?

Comment: if I retry after an error, it always works. Confirmed it a couple of times.

Comment: If I use python shell. It always works. The error just happens if apache and mod_wsgi executes my app (django app). strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I found out its a bug in cryptography module.

See: https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/issues/2299

workaround: place WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

in apache virtualhost configuration e.g.

```
<Directory /var/www/path/to/wsgi>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Also solved my problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643674/google-maps-bad-handshake